# Как правильно составить запрос MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Есть вот такие данные:

```
 [
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "602077959ec21648e7f13563"
    },
    "status": 1,
    "amount": 300,
    "type": "Go",
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2021-02-07T23:28:21.627Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "$date": "2021-02-09T20:58:43.906Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6030c8a32b49d44f10d97f81"
    },
    "status": 1,
    "amount": 12,
    "type": "Go",
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2021-02-20T08:30:27.573Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "$date": "2021-03-26T18:01:27.492Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
  }]
```

И вот такой запрос:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      type: "Go",
      status: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      all: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      },
      today: {
        $sum: "$amount" //Как сюда вывести сумму за определенный период?
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Можно ли составить запрос таким образом, чтоб помимо общей суммы полей еще и вывести общую сумму за определенный период? Вот так, например:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "all": 312,
    "today": 12
  }
]
```

Comment: за определенный период - поконкретнее, пожалуйста

Comment: @entithat за сегодня, например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К ответу выше.
Оператор $facet позволяет параллельно обрабатывать один набор данных различными пайплайнами. Например в одном пайплайне считаем общую сумму, в другом за последнюю неделю через $match.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/